# Ayuda Encontrar la ruta De Las App Instaladas Por El Usuario

Tags: android

Lo que quiero lograr es obtener la ruta de un app que se muestran en listView mediante una pulsación, pero no encuentro la manera de lograr que ocurra si alguno sabe por favor ayuda.
Mi código es este mi código actual:
El código de la activity principal:

```
ListView apps;
 PackageManager packageManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        apps = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
  final List <PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
    .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA); // all apps in the phone
  final List <PackageInfo> packageList1 = packageManager
    .getInstalledPackages(0);

    try {
      packageList1.clear();
      for (int n = 0; n < packageList.size(); n++) 
      {

       PackageInfo PackInfo = packageList.get(n);
       if (((PackInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true) 
        //check weather it is system app or user installed app
       {
        try
        {

          packageList1.add(packageList.get(n)); // add in 2nd list if it is user installed app 
           Collections.sort(packageList1,new Comparator <PackageInfo >() 
             // this will sort App list on the basis of app name
           {
            public int compare(PackageInfo o1,PackageInfo o2) 
            {
             return o1.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString()
               .compareToIgnoreCase(o2.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                   .toString());// compare and return sorted packagelist.
            }
           });


        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
      }
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    Listadapter Adapter = new Listadapter(this,packageList1, packageManager);
    apps.setAdapter(Adapter);
    apps.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String abd=PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION;

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    }
}
`


y de la lista adapter es:` List <PackageInfo> packageList;
 Activity context;
 PackageManager packageManager;


 public Listadapter(Activity context, List <PackageInfo> packageList,
   PackageManager packageManager) {
  super();
  this.context = context;
  this.packageList = packageList;
  this.packageManager = packageManager;

 }

 private class ViewHolder {
  TextView apkName;
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return packageList.size();
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return packageList.get(position);
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  final ViewHolder holder;

  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();

   holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.textView1);

   convertView.setTag(holder);

  } else {

   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);
  String ruta=packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir;
  Drawable appIcon = packageManager
    .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
  String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
    packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
  appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
  holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
  holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
  holder.apkName.setText(appName);

  return convertView;

 }


}
```

Si saben como lograrlo se los agradecería.

Comment: pero cual es el problema? que no realiza correctamente tu código? =0

Comment: No es que quiero encontrar la manera de que con ese código al pisar en el listView busque la ruta de la app que se muestra en el listView. Si sabes como hacerlo por favor dimelo.=)